# How can I equally space items of BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, material-ui, material-components-android

I am using a `BottomNavigationView` from material library, how can I evenly distribute the buttons of the BottomNavigationView in tablet mode, instead of having all the buttons centered?

This is my XML

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bnvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/light_blue_grey"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

And this is how it looks like in tablet
[image]

This is what I want

[image]

I've tried `app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"` and `app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"`, but they still aren't achieving the desired effect.
Hope someone can help me, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Have you considered not using a `BottomNavigationView` at all on tablets? That hasn't been a recommended pattern for a couple of years (when the "navigation rail" pattern was introduced).

Comment: I am required to use the `BottomNavigationView`  so I can't use the `NavigationRail`. However, thank you for your suggestion.